# Systray blocking further Execution of Code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, system-tray

I found [SysTrayIcon.py](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html) to easily create a Systray Icon in Windows.
Problem is, it is blocking the further Execution of Code, as an example, this is how i create my current trayicon:

```
import _tray #This is a simple import of SysTrayIcon.py

#Create SysTray
def EXIT(self): None
def DEBUG(self): print("TEST")
def SHOW(self): print("Showing Main Window")
HOVER = "Foo v"+version
ICON = root+"apr.ico"
MENUE =(('1', None, DEBUG),
        ('2', None, SHOW),
        ('Sub', None, (
            ('Sub 1', None, DEBUG),
            ('Sub 2', None, DEBUG),)))

_tray.SysTrayIcon(ICON, HOVER, MENUE, on_quit=EXIT, default_menu_index=1)
```

if i now add lets say this code:

```
print("This get's executed after the Trayicon is quit.")
```

to the other Code it doesn't get executed until i Quit the Trayicon, how can i avoid/fix said behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use threads to separate the WIN32 API context hold from your app logic. For example, if you replace the direct call with:

```
import threading

def run_systray(icon, hover, menu, **options):
    _tray.SysTrayIcon(icon, hover, menu, **options)

thread = threading.Thread(target=run_systray,
                          args=(ICON, HOVER, MENUE),
                          kwargs={"on_quit": EXIT, "default_menu_index": 1})
thread.start()

print("This gets executed immediately...")

# you can do whatever you want here

# in the end, lets cleanly handle the thread closing:
thread.join()

print("This gets executed only after systray exit...")
```

the `SysTrayIcon` class will happily chat with WIN32 API without blocking the rest of the code until you decide to join the thread back to the main one.